# Using Variables to call attributes of a class

Tags: python, function, class, variables

I'm still a bit new to python, I'm trying to use a variable to call a a specific attribute of a class. However, I think I might be missing something. I've included an example below. Thank you for your help!

```
 class character(object):
        def __init__(self, name, name1, name2):
            self.name = name
            self.name1 = name1
            self.name2= name2

bob = character('bob', 'bob1', 'bob2')


def print_name(var1, var2):
    print(var1.var2)

print_name(bob, 'name1')
```

Comment: [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `getattr`:

```
class character(object):
        def __init__(self, name, name1, name2):
            self.name = name
            self.name1 = name1
            self.name2= name2

bob = character('bob', 'bob1', 'bob2')


def print_name(var1, var2):
    print(getattr(var1,var2))

print_name(bob, 'name1')
```

This is from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a
>   string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes,
>   the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x,
>   'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. If the named attribute does not
>   exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is
>   raised.

Comment: @Gwafa_Hazid No problem !